# Web service configuration storage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created simple web service `MySrv` using `C#`. Now I need to have some specific configuration data like paths, debug level for logging and others. For this reason I was thinking to have static class object called `Config` and load it's data to from ini file or database table. 
  But when I looked to projects `Class View` I found interesting section called `MySrv.Properties` Probably this is place where I can store my configuration?
  Another interesting place for storing configuration is `Web.config`. Is it good manner to use this file for custom settings.

Which way is the nicest to store specific configuration data?

Comment: `web.config` stores settings for the website and allows for a section that can be used to store application settings.  See more at - http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/854/a-beginners-view-webconfig#m

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge web.config will be the best option. You can add your config section in config file and this can be loaded to your custom class very easily. As it is XML, modifying settings will be simplified.